# Can an effect be used to control data request parameters?

Tags: angular, frontend

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly userService = inject(UsersService);

  users = signal<User[]>([]);
  loading = signal<boolean>(false);
  total = signal<number>(0);

  requestParams$ = new BehaviorSubject<{
    limit: number;
    offset: number;
    searchQuery?: string;
  }>({ offset: 1, limit: 10 });

  initUsers: Signal<UserResponse> = toSignal(
    this.requestParams$.pipe(
      distinctUntilParamsChanged(['offset', 'limit', 'searchQuery']),
      switchMap(query => this.userService.getAll(query))
    ),
    { initialValue: { data: [], total: 0 } }
  );

  constructor() {
    effect(
      () => {
        const { data, total } = this.initUsers();
        this.users.set(data);
        this.total.set(total);
        this.loading.update(() => false);
      },
      { allowSignalWrites: true }
    );
  }
```

I receive data if the request params have changed, which glow in the effect, but I don't know if this is a good solution, since signals are new to me.

Comment: effect is in developer preview, is not recommended to use it for production projects and there is no proper documentation for it yet.